# Populating fields from stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, adodb

I was just wondering if my code below is a good way of populating data from database. I have had no issues with this really but I am being taught this and just wondering if it is the best practice.

```
 Public Sub LoadProperty()
    '**Finds the Current Property Data

    'Error Checking
    ' On Error GoTo Err_LoadProperty
    Try

        Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset


        ' Check For Open Connection
        If uDBase Is Nothing Then
            OpenConnection()
            bConnection = True
        End If

        ' Run Stored Procedure - Load Property Record
        uCommand = New ADODB.Command
        With uCommand
            .ActiveConnection = uDBase
            .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandTimeout = 0
                 uCommand.Parameters.Append(uCommand.CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text)))
            .CommandText = "PropertyMaster_LoadRecord"

            uRecSnap = .Execute
        End With

        ' Store Data Values
        Do Until uRecSnap.EOF
            lblPropertyIDValue.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("PropertyID").Value), "", uRecSnap("PropertyID").Value)
            lblSPMReferenceValue.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("SPMReference").Value), "", uRecSnap("SPMReference").Value)
            cmbPropertyManager.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("PropertyManager").Value), "", uRecSnap("PropertyManager").Value)
            txtAddress1.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("AddressLine1").Value), "", uRecSnap("AddressLine1").Value)
            txtAddress2.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("AddressLine2").Value), "", uRecSnap("AddressLine2").Value)
            txtAddress3.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("AddressLine3").Value), "", uRecSnap("AddressLine3").Value)
            txtTown.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Town").Value), "", uRecSnap("Town").Value)
            txtPostCode.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("PostCode").Value), "", uRecSnap("PostCode").Value)
            chkAvailable.Checked = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Availabilty").Value), "", uRecSnap("Availabilty").Value)
            dtpAvailable.Value = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Available").Value), "1/1/1900", uRecSnap("Available").Value)
            chkFactored.Checked = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Factored").Value), 0, uRecSnap("Factored").Value)
            txtFactorName.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("FactorsName").Value), "", uRecSnap("FactorsName").Value)
            txtFactorsEmail.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("FactorsEmail").Value), "", uRecSnap("FactorsEmail").Value)
            dtpPropertyBuilt.Value = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("PropertyBuilt").Value), "1/1/1900", uRecSnap("PropertyBuilt").Value)
            txtPropertyValue.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("PropertyValue").Value), "", uRecSnap("PropertyValue").Value)
            txtMinimumFee.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("MimimumFee").Value), "", uRecSnap("MimimumFee").Value)
            txtCostAuthorisationAmount.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("CostSuthorisationAmount").Value), "", uRecSnap("CostSuthorisationAmount").Value)
            txtCommision.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Commission").Value), "", uRecSnap("Commission").Value)
            chkVacant.Checked = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("Vacant").Value), 0, uRecSnap("Vacant").Value)
            dtpVacant.Value = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("VacantDate").Value), "1/1/1900", uRecSnap("VacantDate").Value)
            txtStartingRent.Text = If(IsDBNull(uRecSnap("StartingRent").Value), "", uRecSnap("StartingRent").Value)

            uRecSnap.MoveNext()
        Loop

        ' Close Connection
        uRecSnap.Close()
        If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
        uRecSnap = Nothing


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Source---" & vbCrLf & ex.Source & vbCrLf & "Problem---" & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SouthSide- Error Reporting")

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know how it would be done, but I think this might be a job for linq-to-sql.

Comment: Are you sure this is **vb.net**? `ADODB`, `Recordset`, `EOF`, `MsgBox`, `vbCrLf`? I would expect to see `<Db>/Connection/Command/Reader`, `MessageBox` and `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå it's vb.net. I've had prior experience with this OP posting vb.net code under the VB6 tag. I would say those are all valid points of review.

Answer (score 5):

It might have been an ok-ish way of doing things... 15 years ago. This code is astonishingly similar to what one would be writing in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) - minus the `Try..End Try` block.

If you want to learn the .NET way of doing things, I **strongly** recommend you remove this from every VB.NET module you're writing:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
```

Things in that namespace exist to make an easier transition between [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)/[vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) - pretty much *everything* in it has an actual [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)-idiomatic equivalent elsewhere in the framework.

- ADODB / ActiveX Data Objects is replaced with [ado.net](/questions/tagged/ado.net), itself rendered obsolete with [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql), itself a predecessor of [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework). But one step at a time - start with [ado.net](/questions/tagged/ado.net).
- `MsgBox` is replaced with `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`
- `vbCrLf` should have been `vbNewLine`, and both are replaced with `Environment.NewLine`

---

You're not including the module-scope fields, and yet the code you posted seems to use plenty... but I don't understand why. You're opening a module-scoped connection, fetching data, and then closing it. Why would that object ever need to exist beyond that? You don't need that Boolean `bConnection`.

ADODB being COM / unmanaged, it doens't implement the `IDisposable` interface. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389223/1188513) for information about proper cleanup of COM objects... which should motivate you to use managed code ;-)

In short:

> Use [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject.aspx) to tidy up COM objects. ADODB is a COM library being used through COM Interop.

---

Now, what you have here is essentially a *Smart UI* pattern: the UI runs the show, and controls everything. That's good for learning how things work, fiddling around and prototyping things, but it's also one of the best ways to create a spaghetti mess out of production code.

Your form should only be responsible for one thing: being a *user interface*. Accessing a database is not the job of a UI, it's that of some *data service*.

You should create a class to act as your *Model*, that would expose a property for each value you're fetching from a database record.

Then the *View* (/form) wouldn't need to know about a database or connections or anything - it would simply display what the *Model* has in store for it. And then when the user makes changes, you can take the modified *Model* and pass it to the same *data service* that provided you with it, to write the modified values into the database.

Read up on the *Model-View-Presenter* pattern for more details.

Answer (score -2):

Consider adding a finally block to safely close the connection.

Comment: That would be a very valid point with an ADO.NET connection, although a `Using` block would be arguably cleaner - thing is, it's an ADODB connection... which isn't `IDisposable`. And it's module-scoped, which suggests it's being used in other methods of the same class; disposing it would render it useless.

Comment: The finally block is to ensure the connection is managed, not to trigger the non-existent dispose method. I've removed the misleading word 'dispose' to prevent further confusion.